# Regex for Phone numbers validation using python

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove phone numbers only in the format 248-524-9344 I'm using

```
r"\(?(\d{3})\)?[ .-]?(\d{3})[ .-]?(\d{4})"
```

but it removes incident number 191112-000475

Comment: If the numbers are in separate lines then you can prefix your regex with `^` and suffix it with `$` which mark the start and end of a line. Otherwise use `\b` instead. Another thing is `[ .-]` I think you may want to escape that period character `[ \.-]`.

Comment: You can test your regex expressions [here](regex101.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\b\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Da5pXb/1).